# What are these two instructions doing?

Tags: assembly, x86

I've got to reverse engineer some assembly code and I'm not sure what these set of instructions are doing.

I know that al is supposed to be the lower byte of eax. But I'm putting the value in edx into it, and edx is a four byte register. So what does al become when I move it?

```
mov     al, [edx]
mov     [ebp+var_19], al
```

Comment: This is using the value in edx as an address, and loading one byte from memory at that address into al.

Answer (score 6):

These instructions are both moving one byte.  The first loads the contents of the 32-bit memory address in the `edx` register into `al`.  The second moves the same  value from `al` into the memory address contained in `ebp` plus a constant offset. It's likely the constant offset is the 19th local stack slot or maybe the 19th parameter word. But that depends on the syntax created by your disassembler.

Comment: `ebp+var_19` is classic IDA syntax, it means `[ebp-19h]`. It's a pity IDA never went over with this confusing syntax.